# c# Console application with validation of usern. it should show two menus: (1) New User (2) Old User For New User :

Tags: c#

1)It should show two menus: (1) New User (2) Old User For New User :
2)For New User : it should ask to enter 
Enter Username : 
Enter Password : 
The length of Username should be max 8. It should not allow special symbols or white space. 
Password length should be max 8. It should contain, special symbols, upper & lower char and number too. 
If user does not enter username and password as per rules then show error message and ask to enter that information again. 
If the details are correctly entered then show message “The Login is created successfully!”

3)Create “TestDb.txt” file in drive and save the login details in text file. 
For Old user : 
It should verify the username and password from the text file and if it’s correct then show message “Login Successful” else “Login Failed” and then ask again to enter the details.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: That homework exercise sounds exciting. Drop bye at a later time and let us know how you got on with it.

Comment: please share this code if anyone tried it

Comment: @Coder Since you didn't post any code there is nothing to try. StackOverflow users won't basically write you codes. SO is not code writing service. Refer to [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and if you are going to have problems with code you make someone will help you.

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't a code writing service. Attempt the task yourself and if you encounter any issues, post your code as a [mcve] and people will be happy to help you. I'd also recommend reading [ask] and taking the [tour]

Comment: @LukasV - I think you meant to direct that to pooja

Comment: @Steve who is pooja? I see Coder who is asking the question.

Comment: I need core solution for both NewUser() and OldUser()

Comment: @Coder what's stopping you from attempting to write the solution yourself?

Comment: @LukasV I have refreshed the page and saw that the OP has changed his display name - it was originally pooja (that's why I thought you spoke to the wrong person)

Comment: You need to try this yourself first and then we can help you if you have troubles.  For starters, 1.  Create a Windows Console Application project in Visual Studio.  2.  In the `Main` method, use `Console.WriteLine` to write text to the screen and `Console.ReadLine` to get input from the user.  This should give you an idea on how to start.  For the `TestDb.txt` file, you can use 'File.ReadAllText` to get the text out of the file and `File.WriteAllText` to put the text into the file.

Answer (score 0):

```
private string IsValidUserName(string name)
        {if (name.Length <= 8)
              {  return name;
        }
        else
        {string str = IsValidUserName("Enter correct UserName");
          return IsValidUserName(name);
        }
    }
private string IsValidPasword(string pwd)
    {if(pwd.Length <= 8)
        { return pwd;
        }
        else
        {return IsValidPasword(pwd);
     }
    }
```

Comment: I have tried this only but don't know how to validate special symbols,white spaces